# OpenGL mipmaps cut out?

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

Is it possible to cut out the last 3 miplevels, so it wont use higher miplevels than max-3 ?

I have problems with high miplevels, they look really bad no matter how much i pad my textures.

Comment: Although you have an answer to your first question, I'm not sure I understand the reason to cut the 3 mips with what you say after. you don't really explain what your problem is...

Comment: the problem is that when it generates the mipmaps from my tilemap, the tiles will eventually start blending in each other in the highest miplevels so much that you can see them leaking colors to other tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See glTexParameter and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL.  I believe this will do what you want.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml